# Failed to find rosdep joystick for package teleop_base on OS

Tags: rosdep, joystick, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, all,
I was trying to follow the tutorial on simulating one robot using stage([link text](http://www.ros.org/wiki/stage/Tutorials/SimulatingOneRobot)), when I run "rosmake teleop_base", it pop up the following errors:
Failed to find rosdep joystick for package teleop_base on OS:ubuntu version:oneiric
[ rosmake ] rosdep check failed to find system dependencies: joystick

I tried to find the joystick dependency on ROS website, but I could not find it.

Can any one give a solution to this problem? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32943/failed-to-find-rosdep-joystick-for-package-teleop_base-on-os...../) by [chenling34401](https://answers.ros.org/users/2274/chenling34401/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2012-04-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since you're using Ubuntu, you should use the binary packages, rather than installing from source. `sudo apt-get install ros-electric-simulator-stage ros-electric-joystick-drivers` I think should install everything you need.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1